# Flask 405 on POST even when POST is present

Tags: python, web, flask

This is my code, a very simple program. Even though **POST** is present, server is showing 405 on POST request. I tried Postman, http-prompt but the result is same "405". On sending **OPTIONS** request to server, only **GET, HEAD and OPTIONS** are shown as allowed methods.Even POST request through a html form is showing 405, of course because server does not even have POST as allowed method despite POST being present in **methods** kwarg.

- I am on a Mac Machine(High Sierra)
- Tried using both *gunicorn* and *inbuilt* flask server.
- Tried using *Postman*, *http-prompt*

```
@app.route('/')
def index(methods=['GET', 'POST']):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render_template('index.html')
    else:
        return 'POST'
```

**index.html** is contains a simple HTML heading.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `methods` parameter values should be set in the route wrapper. Also, it is generally cleaner to check if the request is a `POST` first:

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
   if flask.request.method == 'POST':
      return 'POST'
   return render_template('index.html')
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out, wasted hours because of a silly mistake.

Comment: @Sehwag Glad to help!